# MainActivity is not enclosing class

Tags: java, android

How to fix this problem?

> MainActivity.this is not an enclosing class.

Thank you

```
public class uploadToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    ProgressDialog pd= new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this); //error is here
    pd.setMessage("Wait image uploading!");
    pd.show();
}
}
```

Comment: Just copy the code and paste it in `MainActivity`.

Comment: You have to write this class into `MainActivity` or take a reference of `context` into this class and pass it to `ProgressDialog`

Comment: r u got answer? or problem not solved ahh

Comment: I have not solved the problem . I seek other solutions. if I have a solution I put here.

Comment: why.. my answer not working ahh?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, already the solution you put it helps a little, I have other problems in my mobile app, I'll corrected.

thank you sir :)

Answer (score 2):

in constructor of `AsyncTask`, pass `Context` & use it when you needed

```
public class uploadToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
   private Context mContext;
   public uploadToServer (Context context){
        mContext = context;
   }

   protected void  onPreExecute() {
      super.onPreExecute();
      ProgressDialog pd= new ProgressDialog(mContext); //change is here
      pd.setMessage("Wait image uploading!");
      pd.show();
   }
}
```

Call from `MainActivity` like this,

```
uploadToServer task = new uploadToServer(getApplicationContext());
task.execute();
```